# Image is a line when I try to perform non maximal suppression in matlab

Tags: matlab, canny-operator

So, I wrote this code in matlab which is supposed to perform non-maximal suppression.
essentially it should compare the given point to it's neigbours and if it higher than all neighbours, set this point to 1 else to zero.

when I run the code, the image i have is a line. where might the mistake be.

```
<function newMagnitudeImage = NonMaximalSuppression(magnitude,orientation)
[m,n]=size('Brainweb');

% Discretization of directions
orientationdis= zeros(m,n);

for i = 1  : m
    for j = 1 : n
        if ((orientation(i, j) > 0 ) && (orientation(i, j) < (pi/8)) || (orientation(i, j) > (7*pi/8)) && (orientation(i, j) < (-7*pi/8)))
           orientationdis(i, j) = 0;
        end

        if ((orientation(i, j) > (pi/8)) && (orientation(i, j) < (3*pi/8)) || (orientation(i, j) < (-5*pi/8)) && (orientation(i, j) > (-7*pi/8)))
            orientationdis(i, j) = pi/4;
        end

        if ((orientation(i, j) > (3*pi/8)) && (orientation(i, j) < (5*pi/8)) || (orientation(i, j) < (-3*pi/8)) && (orientation(i, j) > (5*pi/8)))
            orientationdis(i, j) = pi/2;
        end

        if ((orientation(i, j) > (5*pi/8) && (orientation(i, j) <= (7*pi/8)) || (orientation(i, j) < (-pi/8) && (orientation(i, j) > (-3*pi/8)))))
            orientationdis(i, j) = 3*pi/4;
        end
    end
end

newMagnitudeImage = zeros(m, n);

for i = 2  : m-1
    for j = 2 : n-1
        if (orientationdis(i, j) == 0)
            if (magnitude(i, j) > magnitude(i, j - 1) && magnitude(i, j) > magnitude(i, j + 1))
                newMagnitudeImage(i, j) = magnitude(i, j);
            else
               newMagnitudeImage(i, j) = 0;
            end
        end

        if (orientationdis(i, j) == 45)
            if (magnitude(i, j) > magnitude(i + 1, j - 1) && magnitude(i, j) > magnitude(i - 1, j + 1))
                newMagnitudeImage(i, j) = magnitude(i, j);
            else
               newMagnitudeImage(i, j) = 0;
            end
        end

        if (orientationdis(i, j) == 90)
            if (magnitude(i, j) > magnitude(i - 1, j) && magnitude(i, j) > magnitude(i + 1, j))
                newMagnitudeImage(i, j) = magnitude(i, j);
            else
                newMagnitudeImage(i, j) = 0;
            end
        end

        if (orientationdis(i, j) == 135)
            if (magnitude(i, j) > magnitude(i - 1, j - 1) && magnitude(i, j) > magnitude(i + 1, j + 1))
                newMagnitudeImage(i, j) = magnitude(i, j);
            else
               newMagnitudeImage(i, j) = 0;
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: I edited my answer to include a 1/2 line solution for you

Answer (score 0):

In the top section of code, you discretize between 0 and 3*pi/4 in radians, but in the bottom half, you are checking in terms of degrees. You should change the two so that they match up (i.e. change the ==45 to == pi/4, etc)

It seems like there might be more problems in the code though- why are you only discretizing between 0 and 135 degrees?

EDIT: A much shorter version of the same code [Requires image processing toolbox]:

```
orientationdis = mod(round(orientation/(pi/4)),4)*pi/4 %map orientation to correct value of from 0 to pi, rounded to the nearest pi/4
newMagnitudeImage = (imdilate(orientation,[0 1 0; 1 1 1; 0 1 0])==orientation).*magnitude; %Find the maximum value in each neighborhood, compare to the original values, set non-maximum values to 0 and maximum values to original value from magnitude
```

If you're not using orientationdis elsewhere in your code, you only need the second line.

Comment: I did so because I considered that 0 covers 180, 45 covers -135 and 90 covers -90

Answer (score 0):

I hope that I understand, but you can apply a Sliding Neighborhood Operations with `nlfilter`.

For example you can do:

```
I = randi([1,10],10,10);
fun = @(x) max(x(:));
I2 = nlfilter(I,[3 3],fun); %calculate the maximum of the neighborhood.

ind = I==I2; %is each element a local maximum ?

%suppression if the value is not the maximum of the neighborhood.

I(~ind) = NaN;
```

`nlfilter`required the image processing toolbox